# Malloc Array, Conditional jump on uninitialized values

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am using Malloc to create an array of pointers. However I am recieving the valgrind Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) whenever I try to reference something in one of the indexes in the array. In my code somethimes there will be something stored at the index[] and sometimes there won't. For example, there could be a pointer stored at value 1, 4, 6.. but not in any of the others. My goal is to be able to determine that without valgrind errors!

```
typedef struct{
    char* symbol;
    void* datapointer;
    void* nextstruct;
}Entry;
void main(){
int sizeHint = 10000; //size of array
Entry** arrayOfPointers = malloc(sizeHint * sizeof(Entry*));

//For the sake of keeping this simple, say I stored something
//in a bunch of indexes in the array but NOT at 5

if(arrayOfPointers[5] != NULL){
  //this is where my error comes, as it reads
  //conditional jump or move depends on uninitilised value
  //my goal is to be able to determine if something is stored at an index, and 
  //do something if its not stored
}

}
```

Comment: You should use `calloc()` instead: it performs the multiplication for you, checking for overflow, and initializes the memory to zero.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: The current C Standard does not mandate that a bit pattern of all `0`s would make a pointer variable be equal the null-pointer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471057/malloc-array-conditional-jump-on-uninitialized-values/42471123#comment72082868_42471123

Answer (score 2):

> my goal is to be able to determine if something is stored at an index

After allocating the pointer-array set it to all `NULL`s before using it:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeHint; ++i)
{
  arrayOfPointers[i] = NULL;
}
```

`malloc()` doesn't do this for you.

From the C11 Standard (draft) 7.22.3.4/2:

> The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and
>   whose value is indeterminate.

Comment: Better yet, use `calloc()`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: From the Standard's perspective `0`ing out the pointer values does not necessarily end up with them being equal to null-pointer values.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: 7.22.3.2: "***The calloc function** [...] The space is initialized to all bits zero. 296) [...] 296): Note that this need not be the same as the representation of [...] a null pointer
constant.*"

Comment: Ah, right. In practice, `NULL` is all zero bits on all relevant architectures. I think a simple `static_assert` that `NULL` is all zeroes would be sufficient to safely use `calloc` here.

Answer (score 0):

After the allocation via `malloc` the memory will not automatically be initialised to `NULL` (or anything else). It still can contain anything which is why valgrind warns you about the comparison.

To initialise the entire allocation to 0 (which is treated as `NULL` by at least [GCC](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Null-Pointer-Constant.html), [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stddef_8h.html#a070d2ce7b6bb7e5c05602aa8c308d0c4) and [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d69tdh6e.aspx)) you can use:

```
memset(arrayOfPointers, 0, sizeHint * sizeof(Entry*));
```

The memset function is provided by the `string.h` header file.

Comment: *"Now you can be sure that all elements are NULL*" unfortunately, you can't. Please see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471057/malloc-array-conditional-jump-on-uninitialized-values/42471123#comment72082868_42471123).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Changed the answer slightly.

Comment: Although this isn't explicitly wrong anymore, still the term "*usually*" without further explanation of what this could mean does not make the answer a good answer ...